# $ 0 $ locates in the continuous spectrum of Schrodinger operators?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

This is question is motivated by [Non-closed range space of Laplace operators?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341383/non-closed-range-space-of-laplace-operators). We aim to determine what kind of potential will make corresponding schrodinger operators possess non-closed range.

For Schrodinger operator with Kato-Relich potentials
\begin{equation*}
-\Delta + V(x): H^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^3),
\end{equation*}
where $ V(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) + L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3) $.
 What conditions can we add on $ V $ such that $ 0 $ locates in the continuous spectrum of above operators?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course not, for example you could take $V=1$. A less trivial remark is that even if you require $V$ to go to zero at infinity, that won't be enough to obtain this conclusion. You can in fact still have pure point spectrum for such a $V$.

Comment: @Christian Remling  Thank you for comments, could you point out the latter example with pure point spectrum? Besides, I have investigated that  the Schrodinger operators with Coulomb potential and short-range potential could achieve the goal ($ 0 \in \sigma_c $). Can we have a more general result for the potential?

Comment: The examples are essentially one-dimensional; the potential is spherically symmetric. You could try to check the corresponding (rather large) literature. If you want to run an internet search, I would try something like "spectral properties of 1D SO with decaying potentials" perhaps.