# Partial well-posedness results on Schrödinger operators?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

Set $ A_i:= -\Delta + V_i :H^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^3), \ i =1,2   $, where 
\begin{equation*}
 V_1 = 0,  \ \ (\textrm{No interaction}) \\
 V_2 = - \frac{\gamma}{\vert x \vert}, \gamma >0, \ \ (\textrm{Coulumb potential}).
\end{equation*}
By the fact that $ 0 \in \sigma_c(A_i), \ i =1,2 $,

**Remark:** This result could be found in Chapter 7, 10 in  "G. Teschl: Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics - With Applications to Schrödinger Operators (2014)".

we know 
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{N}(A_i) = 0, \ \overline{\mathcal{R}(A_i)} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \\
 \ A^{-1}_i \ \textrm{unbounded} \ (i =1,2)
\end{equation*}
**Question:** Can we find a bounded restriction for $ A^{-1}_i $, that is, there exist $ \mathcal{B}_i \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A_i) $ such that $ A^{-1}_i|_{\mathcal{B}_i} $ are bounded respectively?

Good references will be welcome. Thank you in advance!

**Notice:** This question is highly related to ([Non-closed range space of Laplace operators?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341383/non-closed-range-space-of-laplace-operators)) and ([$ 0 $ locates in the continuous spectrum of Schrodinger operators?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341607/0-locates-in-the-continuous-spectrum-of-schrodinger-operators)).

Comment: What kind if conditions do you want $\mathcal{B}_i$ to satisfy? For instance, the situation becomes trivial if you allow finite-dimensional $\mathcal{B}_i$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  Now i have no mature thoughts. Maybe you can give me some examples to feel? Even the finite dimensional case will be welcome. Of course the bigger and infinite-dimensional will be better.

Comment: Well, every linear operator from a finite dimensional space to any normed space is continuous, so you can choose $\mathcal{B}_i$ to be any finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{R}(A_i)$ and the restriction of $A_i^{-1}$ to $\mathcal{B}_i$ will be continuous.

Comment: @JochenGlueck This is a naive example i ignore. Ok, now the focus is on the infinite-dimensional case. Is there some known research on it?

Comment: You can, for instance, integrate the spectral measure of your operator over the constant function with value $1$ over any subset of the spectrum that does not contain $0$ in its closure; the result will be a spectral projection $P$ such that the restriction of your operator to the range of $P$ is countinuously invertible. Hence, $\mathcal{B}_i$ can be chosen as the range of any such projection $P$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Can this way yield an explicit expression for one infinite-dimensional range?